# PyCharm unsolved reference 'linspace' in '__init__.pyi | __init__.pyi'

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm, warnings

PyCharm gives me an unsolved reference warning when I use np.linspace.

```py
import numpy as np
ls = np.linspace(0, 100, 5)
```

```py
Cannot find reference 'linspace' in '__init__.pyi | __init__.pyi'
```

There is no problem with running the code, numpy is installed correctly and it runs fine. I'm just trying to get rid of the warning (I know I can change the warning settings or add a comment to ignore this line but I want to get to the root of the problem).

What I've tried so far:

- Set project root as source directory
- File --> Invalidate Caches / Restart

I read somewhere that it might be related to the _*all*_ variable in numpy's _*init*_.pyi, but it looks like this:

```py
__all__ = [
    "linspace",
    "logspace",
    ...
```

Comment: Does using anything else from `numpy` work?

Comment: Strange, `np.logspace` gives the same warning, `np.array` gives no warning.

Comment: What PyCharm version do you have? Looks similar to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46169

Comment: @user2235698 Yes this was the problem indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As commented by user2235698, I was running an older version of PyCharm 2020.3 which contains a bug (should be fixed in version 2020.3.3), see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46169.

To fix it manually I changed the following lines in numpy's _*init*_.pyi:

```py
from numpy.core.function_base import (
    linspace
```

to

```py
from numpy.core.function_base import (
    linspace as linspace
```